# Chrome: Print is not working in latest version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

We have two types of article in application which is HTML and PDF.
If I go ahead and do "window.print()" in HTML article directly, it works without any problem.
Now, If I visit PDF page which is loaded from "embbed and object" tab and then go back to HTML page to print, it's not working. It's working fine in all other browser and older version of chrome but not working in latest version of chrome. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: What is "embed and object" tab?

Comment: Any error in the console? You need to show your code.

Comment: No error in console. It's simple HTML print with "window.print()" function.

Comment: You need to provde precise details of how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I probably have the same issue. [Here](https://traqdev.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_pdf_file_with_print.pdf) is a pdf that used to print on load in the previous version of Chrome. And [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/15456914?hl=en) is a Chrome Support thread that seems to not have been addressed yet.

Comment: @yazanpro I guess this is a feature I'm not familiar with, how does a PDF print on load, rather than when you click on the printer icon?

Comment: @Barmar You can inject "JavaScript" command in the PDF itself for that purpose. The referenced file does print if opened in IE or downloaded and opened in Adobe Reader.

Comment: @yazanpro This question seems to be different, there's an HTML page involved as well.

Comment: @Barmar You're probably right. The fact that he's referring to "Print PDF problem in the latest version of Chrome" made me think it's most likely the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for Update:

This issue has been no longer reproducible in Chrome Version: Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce the problem just open a pdf directly on chrome, then open developer tools on that pdf page, then go on console and write the print();  command

Tada! Problem detected,

this started happening to me on latest version as well, Thank god I'm not the only one.